# Python how to make a curl request with username/password

Tags: python, curl

Trying to hit an api which returns a json. Documentation says to hit it in this fashion:

curl --user username:password "https://api.company.com/dummyapi.json"

Works like a champ from the command line and in PHP. I'm new to Python. How do I do mimic this in Python? I've tried requests and subprocess.call but I keep getting a bad request response from the server saying that credentials were not provided.

Comment: What have you tried in python? What code? Requests has a section in the docs on [authentication](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/)

Comment: You nailed it Andy. Hadn't seen that documentation. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

To do what `curl` does, in python you can use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). First of all you have to **install** it :

```
pip install requests
```

Then sending an http request is as easy as :

```
from requests import get
response = get('https://api.company.com/dummyapi.json', auth=('user', 'pass'))
```

Now `response` holds all information returned from that api. Use the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) for more info, and in particular the section about [authentication](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/).